# i am trying to write an if statement for a specific range of cells but i got the same formula applied to that range.

Tags: excel, if-statement, vba

```
Sub RebateCalculation()

    For x = 2 To 400 
        If Cells(x, 29) = (-0.2) Then
            Range(Cells(x, 25), Cells(x, 25)).Formula = "=0.06*Q4-Q4+O4/M4"
        ElseIf Cells(x, 29) = (-0.333333333333333) Then
            Range(Cells(x, 25), Cells(x, 25)).Formula = "=0.05*Q4-Q4+O4/M4"
        ElseIf Cells(x, 29) = (-1.4) Then
            Range(Cells(x, 25), Cells(x, 25)).Formula = "0.05 * Q4 - Q4 + O4 / M4"
        Else
            Cells(x, 25) = ""
        End If
    Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: all your formula appear to be the same

Comment: you have currently specified all three formula as fixed strings `"=0.06*Q4-Q4+Q4/M4"` try `"=0.06*" & Cell & "-" & cell & "+" & cell & "/" & cell2` where you increment the cell string in in each for loop

Comment: A BIG thank you. This formula structure works very well. I added a few fixes but this is exactly what I needed. Thank you! The new formula with your input is:"=(0.06*" & Cells(x, 17) & "-" & Cells(x, 17) & "+" & Cells(x, 15) & ")" & "/" & Cells(x, 13).

Comment: @user3718442 Accept answer please if it helped you solve (i included my comment in answer options)

Answer (score 0):

Here is a simple example. to see it work enter 1 to 10 in the first 10 rows of column A and then run it.

I have used `FormulaR1C1` because it allows you to easily loop through and modify formula depending on a variable. As you can see you make sure the "R1C1" is entered as a complete string reference to a cell and it can be made up of a few strings and variables `"R"& rowNumber & "C" & columnNumber`

```
Sub addEquation()

For i = 1 To 10

    If Cells(i, 1).Value = 1 Then
        Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=10*R" & i & "C1"
    Else
        Cells(i, 2).FormulaR1C1 = "=500*R" & i & "C1"
    End If

Next i

End Sub
```

The other option as is instead of specifying all three formula as fixed strings "=0.06*Q4-Q4+Q4/M4" try "=0.06*" & Cell & "-" & cell & "+" & cell & "/" & cell2 where you increment the cell string in in each for loop